# Export tables keeping the source table structure

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

Suppose, I have sql server **"A"** and sql server **"B"**

I want to export Tables from database a1 (in sql server A) to database b1 (in sql server B) using sql server import export wizard keeping the key definitions

But,when I export ,a new table get created in b1 with all data,but key is not established there,what is the way to transfer/export so that I can get exact structure and also data of the source table

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could look into creating a table script, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698310/backup-a-single-table-with-its-data-from-a-database-in-sql-server-2008 ... this I believe would create a series of statements, including key definitions and inserts, which would attempt to recreate the current state of your table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import / Export database with SQL Server Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126571/import-export-database-with-sql-server-server-management-studio)